# Laravel: cannot access resource collection in middleware

Tags: php, json, laravel, resources, middleware

I'm trying to create a middleware which wraps the returned response into a uniform JSON response for my API. This will ensure that all API responses have the same base structure which looks like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {...}
}
```

Now this is the middleware I am currently using:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class ApiResponseWrapper
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        /** @var Response $response */
        $response = $next($request);
        $original = $response->getOriginalContent();

        $content = [
            'success' => $response->isSuccessful(),
            'data' => $original,
        ];

        $jsonContent = json_encode($content, JsonResponse::DEFAULT_ENCODING_OPTIONS);
        $response->setContent($jsonContent);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

The two key points of this middleware are:

1. The `$original = $response->getOriginalContent();` line gets the content of the response to wrap.
2. The content needs to be a string in order to be set as the new content. That's why I `json_encode` the `$content` with the default encoding options for a JSON response.

The problem arises when I want to pass a paginated `ResourceCollection` into the middleware. The controller method looks like this:

```php
public function index(): AnonymousResourceCollection
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = auth()->user();

    return PostResource::collection($user->posts->paginate(20));
}
```

Normally, the `->paginate(...)` method does not exist in a Laravel Collection. It is a macro taken from here: [gist.github.com/simonhamp/549e8821946e2c40a617c85d2cf5af5e](https://gist.github.com/simonhamp/549e8821946e2c40a617c85d2cf5af5e).

If I now hit the endpoint that calls the `index()` method, the expected output is something like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "data": [
            <PostResource as JSON object>
        ],
        "meta": {...},
        "links": {...},
    }
}
```

But what I actually get is this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        <Post Model as array>
    ]
}
```

I thought I might have to call a method to encode the `$original` (which is of type `Illuminate\Support\Collection`) into a paginated resource collection, but I didn't find one.

All other responses are fine. For example on another controller method I simply return an array or a string and they are wrapped as expected.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong here?

---

**Edit:**

I also tried to add this before the `$content` variable is set:

```php
if (method_exists($original, 'toArray')) {
    $original = $original->toArray();
}
```

It results in the same output for `ResourceCollections`.

Comment: What happen if you use `'data' => $original->toArray()`?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte It results in the same output, not the output wanted.

Comment: Side note: instead of calling `->paginate` on the collection, you should be able to call it on the query builder for that relation: `$user->posts()->paginate(20)` without any macro. That would also perform better as the filtering and limiting is done at database level, not with in memory objects

Comment: @mdexp normally, you would be right. In my case however, `posts` is actually a Model accessor: [Defining An Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor). You are probably right about the performance and I will definetly look into this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the variable types and looking through the Laravel API, I found that the easiest solution was to just check if the response is a `JsonResponse` and get the rendered pagination data from it:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    /** @var Response $response */
    $response = $next($request);
    $content = [
        'success' => $response->isSuccessful(),
    ];

    if ($response instanceof JsonResponse) {
        /** @var JsonResponse $response */

        $data = $response->getData(true);

        $content = array_merge($content, $data);
    } else {
        $content['data'] = $response->getOriginalContent();
    }

    $jsonContent = json_encode($content, JsonResponse::DEFAULT_ENCODING_OPTIONS);
    $response->setContent($jsonContent);

    return $response;
}
```

This results in the expected responses for my use case:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        <PostResource as JSON object>
    ],
    "meta": {...},
    "links": {...},
}
```

Also note that I originally specified the `data`, `meta` and `links` keys within the wrapping `data` key.
I find the result above a bit prettier because I got around double wrapped `data`.

I hope this will help anyone who came across this question!